# How to get the foreign and primary key details for a table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2008, foreign-key, metadata

I would like to use 2 queries, one that lists all the foreign keys for a given table with the following information `Schema name, foreign table name` and the other that lists all the primary keys.

Is this query that lists the primary keys correct:

```
select syssc.name as schemaname , cast(c.name as  varchar(255)) as foreign_table , 
cast(p.name as varchar(255)) as primary_table 
from sysobjects f 
inner join sysobjects c on  f.parent_obj = c.id 
inner join sysreferences r on f.id =  r.constid 
inner join sysobjects p on r.rkeyid = p.id 
inner  join syscolumns rc on r.rkeyid = rc.id and r.rkey1 = rc.colid 
inner  join syscolumns fc on r.fkeyid = fc.id and r.fkey1 = fc.colid 
left join  syscolumns rc2 on r.rkeyid = rc2.id and r.rkey2 = rc.colid 
left join  syscolumns fc2 on r.fkeyid = fc2.id and r.fkey2 = fc.colid 
inner join sys.tables syst on rc.id=syst.object_id 
inner join sys.schemas syssc on syst.schema_id=syssc.schema_id 
where  f.type =  'F' AND c.name in ('table name' )
```

This is the query that i use now to get the foreign keys

```
select syssc.name as schemaname ,cast(c.name as  varchar(255)) as foreign_table ,  
cast(p.name as varchar(255)) as primary_table 
from sysobjects f 
inner join sysobjects c on  f.parent_obj = c.id 
inner join sysreferences r on f.id =  r.constid 
inner join sysobjects p on r.rkeyid = p.id 
inner  join syscolumns rc on r.rkeyid = rc.id and r.rkey1 = rc.colid 
inner  join syscolumns fc on r.fkeyid = fc.id and r.fkey1 = fc.colid 
left join  syscolumns rc2 on r.rkeyid = rc2.id and r.rkey2 = rc.colid 
left join  syscolumns fc2 on r.fkeyid = fc2.id and r.fkey2 = fc.colid 
inner join sys.tables syst on rc.id=syst.object_id 
inner join sys.schemas syssc on syst.schema_id=syssc.schema_id 
where  f.type =  'F' and p.name in ('table name')
```

Kindly check whether these queries are the right ones and the efficient ones.

Comment: What version of SQL Server please?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 Express Edition.

Comment: And are you trying to get the columns in `table name` that are referenced by foreign keys in other tables, or the columns in `table name` that reference other tables?

Comment: @Aaron: It was late night here,so only i was not able to reply to you. I needed both the tables and the columns but have to run separate queries now. I will use your queries in your reply. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should become familiar with the new catalog views. The old sysobjects, syscolumns etc. have been deprecated and are only provided for backward compatibility reasons - they shouldn't be used for new development and old code should eventually transition to the new objects.

Here is a query that will get both sides of the columns involved in foreign keys:

```
SELECT 
        constraint_name   = OBJECT_NAME(fkc.constraint_object_id), 
        foreign_schema    = SCHEMA_NAME(child.[schema_id]), 
        foreign_table     = child.name, 
        foreign_column    = child_cols.name, 
        referenced_schema = SCHEMA_NAME(referenced.[schema_id]),
        referenced_table  = referenced.name, 
        referenced_column = referenced_cols.name
    FROM sys.foreign_key_columns AS fkc
    INNER JOIN sys.tables AS child
    ON fkc.parent_object_id = child.[object_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.tables AS referenced
    ON fkc.referenced_object_id = referenced.[object_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS referenced_cols
    ON fkc.parent_column_id = referenced_cols.column_id
    AND referenced_cols.[object_id] = referenced.[object_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS child_cols
    ON fkc.referenced_column_id = child_cols.column_id
    AND child_cols.[object_id] = child.[object_id]
    WHERE referenced.name = 'table name'
    -- if you want the tables that a child table references, use this instead:
    -- WHERE child.name = 'table name'
    ORDER BY fkc.parent_column_id;
```

And this one is much simpler, just for the tables involved:

```
SELECT 
    constraint_name = name, 
    foreign_schema = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id),
    foreign_table = OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id), 
    referenced_schema = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referenced_object_id),
    referenced_table = OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id)
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) = 'table name'
-- if you want the tables that a child table references, use this instead:
-- WHERE OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) = 'table name';
```

**EDIT** adding some links to documentation (these mostly fall within the SQL Server 2008 R2 hierarchy but they're roughly equivalent for SQL Server 2008 as well):

- [Catalog Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174365.aspx)
- [Querying the Catalog Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189082.aspx)
- [Querying the Catalog Views FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345522.aspx)
- [Metadata Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187812.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your help. These queries really help me. I did not have the in depth knowledge on the database objects, hence had to use a suggested query, however i felt that it was a bit unclear for me. Hence I posted here. I will learn about the database objects, hope msdn has some good documentation, else you can suggest me one. Your script is clear and easy to understand than the one i have.. Thank you.